# Get time zone with time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display DateTime with an abbreviated Time Zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180370/how-to-display-datetime-with-an-abbreviated-time-zone)

Iam displaying time from database table. Now I want to display that datetime in my webpage with timezone like  IST,PST,EST,CST.

By using C# datetime formatspecifiers.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(ds_E2A.Tables[0].Rows[0][2]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zz")
```

The above displays like this  `11/12/2012 21:10:10 +05`. Instead of +05 I want to display `IST`,`PST`,`EST`.

I used `Convert.ToDateTime(ds_E2A.Tables[0].Rows[0][2]).ToString("r")`. 
It displays `GMT` at the end of time. But I want to display current timezone.

I used `TimeZoneInfo` and `TimeZone` classes in C#.

If Iam getting data from india I want to display as `IST` or any other country `PST` or `CST`

I want to display as `11/12/2012 21:10:10 PST`

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/ there are 11 distinct time zones which are UTC + 5 hours. When the system retrieves a time from the database with an offset of +5 hours, how should it know which of the 11 time zone abbreviations to display?

Comment: +1 for @AdamRalph Thats a good link from timedate.com. Atleast I want to get the major timezones like `PST`,`EST`

Comment: You can also give a look at [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.90).aspx). Adding that to what is given above, you should find something interesting.